# Deleting common characters in 2 different strings

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsstring, uitextfield

I am new to Xcode and iPhone developing. I am stuck in a problem.

I have two textFields and i want to compare these strings. If there is any common character then it should be omitted/deleted, and the new string is displayed in another textfield.

The common character can be at any location in the string and only one character is omitted at a time(in for loop).

Comment: Do you have to keep the order of the two strings?

Comment: Define common character a little better please? For example, does it just need to be in the string, or in the same position in the two strings. Take `abcdefg` and `gfedcba`. If it just needs to contain the same character, then the strings would be blank. But if it needs to be in the same location then the strings would be `d` after stripping common characters.

Comment: The common character can be at any location in string but one one character have to be omitted at a time(in for loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wrote this! I havent found cases where it doesnt work! Tell me if it works for you!

```
 NSMutableString *shortString; //put your shortest string in here
    NSMutableString *longString; //put your longest string in here

    //index for characters to be removed in short string
    int characterIndexesShort[shortString.length], characterIndexesLong[longString.length];
    int commonCharactersShort = 0, commonCharactersLong = 0;
    int cut = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < shortString.length; i++)
    {
        int oldLongCharCount = commonCharactersLong;
        char currentLetter = [shortString characterAtIndex:i];

        for(int j = 0; j < longString.length; j++)
        {
            if(currentLetter  == [longString characterAtIndex:j])
                characterIndexesLong[commonCharactersLong++] = j;
        }

        if(commonCharactersLong != oldLongCharCount)
            characterIndexesShort[commonCharactersShort++] = i;
    }
    //At this point you will have arrays containing the indexes of the common characters in both strings


    for(int i = 0; i < commonCharactersLong; i++)
    {
        NSRange range;
        range.location = characterIndexesLong[i];
        range.length = 1;
        [longString replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < commonCharactersShort; i++)
    {
        NSRange range;
        range.location = characterIndexesShort[i] - cut;
        range.length = 1;
        [shortString replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
        cut++;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe make a method with this that takes 2 strings as arguments. Then at the start check which is the longest and which the shortest and store them in the corresponding mutable strings.

Comment: Thanks for the code. If both strings are equal then? And why this code is for short and long strings?

Comment: If the longer string is in the shortString it doesnt work, as you noticed the for loops at the bottom are slightly different. If they are equal it works in either way. If you like my answer please accept it, people on stack overflow will be more willing to help you if you accept answers.

Comment: Im going through it now, i dont think the problem is the lengths of the actual strings but rather how many matches they have in the two bottom for loops. This is what programming is all about, an idea that only works for specific cases when you first write it, then after a little bit of debug and modifications it all works!

Comment: Yeah exactly. lengths not the problem its repeated characters. e.g usmaan and ali be two strings and if i display 2nd string i got only "i" first two are removed